# How do I label a desaturation colour map from a sublayer?

Tags: blazor, syncfusion, syncfusion-blazor

I'm trying to overlay a desaturation colour map of simulated pollution levels onto a city map (from OpenStreetMaps) in Blazor using Syncfusion Maps, but the legend has stopped displaying.

I'm fairly certain the issue is to do with the colour map being the sublayer, as it works fine in my app using example code, but the same example code fails to render the legend when I use it as a sublayer.
The sublayer legend seems to work when I discretise the data into sections and specify a colour for each (i.e., Syncfusion range colour mapping), but not when I input a list of colours to form a gradient for desaturation colour mapping. It still tries to render a legend in this case, but leaves it blank, so its existence is only evident from the bounding box I added.

The map itself renders as I expect it to, it's just the legend that doesn't show.

Comment: Provide a sample in [blazor repl](https://www.telerik.com/blazor-ui/repl) if you want to any chance of get an answer. Currently, your question is unanswerable

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we will fix this issue and the fix will be available by end of this month.

Answer (score 0):

The reported issue- “**When multiple colors are added to single color-mapping object of sublayer shape map, legend shape is hidden**” has been fixed and it is included in this version **v22.2.10**. Please update the Maps package to the latest version and refer the latest version of the script in your application to resolve the reported issue.